# C# - Regex match pattern, replace and capture line number [From Txt File]

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I am relatively new to C#.

I am reading the contents of a text file, applying Regex Pattern to find and replace the matching IP address. Also, capture the line number in which the text was replace.

**The contents of the text file: ips.txt**

> The address of the computerA 192.168.1.1
>
> Random IP Addresses 199.255.255.1 192.168.3.1
>
> 121.225.56.6
>
> ComputerA -  192.168.1.1

**The desired output:**

> Line 1: 192.168.1.1 ---> IP-Address-1
>
> Line 3: 199.255.255.1 ---> IP-Address-2
>
> Line 3: 192.168.3.1 ---> IP-Address-3
>
> Line 5: 121.225.56.6 ---> IP-Address-4
>
> Line 7: 192.168.1.1 ---> IP-Address-1

**The Code:**

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string ipname = "IP-ADDRESS";
        string pattern = (@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");
        string _ipdata = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"ips.txt"))
        {
            _ipdata = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(_ipdata, pattern);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < collection.Count)
        {
            foreach (Match m in collection)
            {
                _ipdata = _ipdata.Replace(m.Value, ipname+(i+1));
                i++;    
            }
            Console.WriteLine(_ipdata);
        }     
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**I managed to get the following Output:**

> The address of the computerA IP-ADDRESS1
>
> Random IP Addresses IP-ADDRESS2 IP-ADDRESS3
>
> IP-ADDRESS4
>
> ComputerA -  IP-ADDRESS1

**Update:**

With the below answer, able to get the desired output.

However, looking for two outputs. The one above and the desired output as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to read the entire file into a string to process it later. A more effective way would be reading from input string line by line and process each line as you read it. This also will make it easier to maintain a line number counter.
2. As you read a line you may easily extract all IP addresses from it using the following construct: `ipAddrRegex.Matches(line).Cast<Match>()`, where `ipAddrRegex` and a pre-created `Regex` instance (see the code below). `.Cast<Match>()` converts match collection to `IEnumerable<Match>`, which simplifies iteration through the matches.
3. A particular IP address is the matched string so it's retrieved as `match.Value`.
4. As you've retrieved an IP address, you need to look up for it in the already found addresses (to give it proper "IP-ADDRESS-X" name). Those already found addresses are best managed with a dictionary (see `foundAddresses` in the code).

```
string ipname = "IP-ADDRESS-";
var ipAddrRegex = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
int lineNum = 1;
int addressNum = 1;
var foundAddresses = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string line;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"ips.txt"))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foreach (var match in ipAddrRegex.Matches(line).Cast<Match>())
        {
            string addressName;
            if (!foundAddresses.TryGetValue(match.Value, out addressName))
            {
                addressName = ipname + addressNum.ToString();
                foundAddresses.Add(match.Value, addressName);
                addressNum++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: {1} ---> {2}", lineNum, match.Value, addressName);
        }
        lineNum++;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oqmav4

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I am trying to output this result onto a text file with help of StreamWriter. How can we generate a modified file with the same format of as that of ips.txt but with replaced ip values.

Comment: Please check the update! Trying to replace the ip with the string in the original ips.txt file and display the desired output.

Comment: @Tango, I don't quite get what you would like to see in the output file. It is the duplicate of the console output or should it be the input file with each IP address replaced with `IP-ADDRESS-X`?

Comment: yes, replaced with IP-ADDRESS-X (ips.txt) and output produced from your answer in a different file